# Gap probability for i.i.d. random variables

Tags: probability, reference-request, probability-distributions, random-variables, poisson-process

Given a set $\{X_1,\ldots,X_N\}$ of real i.i.d. random variables, drawn from a common parent pdf $p_X(x)$, what is the probability that, given one random variable taking value in $(t-dt,t)$, there are no other random variables in the interval $(t,t+s)$ and there is another random variable in $(t+s,t+s+ds)$? In other words, what is the probability of an empty gap of size $s$ to the right of the point $t$ on the real axis, as a function of $s,t$ (given $N$ and $p_X(x)$)?

Is there a general formula for finite $N$, and/or an asymptotic formula for large $N$?

The book by Mehta on random matrices reports an asymptotic argument on pag. 11-12 that does not mention/require either the parent pdf or the point $t$, and the gap pdf turns out to be exponential, $\exp(-\rho s)\rho ds$, where $\rho$ is related to the "average density of points", however the argument is very heuristic and not terribly clear in my view. Is there a way to formalize it a bit better? Many thanks, folks.

Comment: Possible reduction: solve the question when $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, and then use the distribution function to generalize to any distribution.

Comment: @D.Thomine thanks for your comment. The thing is, this must be a very well known problem, with a clear answer (that I've failed to find anywhere, though, at least in a very neat form). I've added the 'reference request' tag, to make clear that I am rather looking for a ready meal (which must be out there somehwere)...